# Could not find or load main class layout.BoxLayoutDemo

Tags: java, swing, awt

i'm a java - novice and am trying to run the following code from docs.oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java

I'm compiling through cmd, have latest jdk, "path" - variable contains both jdk/bin and jre/bin and the .java file compiles well or at least doesn't report an error and produces .class file, which I see in folder. When I try to run the class, however, I tend too get :

> Error: Could not find or load main class layout.BoxLayoutDemo
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: layout.BoxLayoutDemo

Suspects?

Comment: see the links and answer provided

Answer (score 0):

you did not create package `layout`, but you are importing it, so  either create `layout` package or remove it.

save class `BoxLayoutDemo` in folder `layout`

Comment: without the "package layout" statement compiled, i get the same error

Comment: folder "layout" is also tried out, same result

Comment: CLASSPATH issue. I have recently installed tomcat and set "classpath" for first time for tomcat's servlet-api.jar, without adding my working dir to classpath. now i have added it, restart, and it executes. THANKS FOR THE LINKS ABOVE !